# How to debug Web API model binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I've been working with quite some Web API projects now and find myself bumping into the same problem every time and that's when I do a POST or GET the value / model etc is null or I get a 404.

There is a checklist like:
- did I use the correct content-type?
- has routing been set up correctly
- is the signature of the model that I'm posting really the same as the model that the endpoint accepts?

It would be nice if there is a trace one could follow where it fails. Now it just looks like a black box, you put something in and it works or not, if it doesn't: see checklists or SO.

Is there something that you can setup in Web API so you can debug the model binding process?

Answer (score 1):

I would implement action filter.

One of the methods that can be overridden there is :

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
```

In this action you can check the response status and if it is an error to perform all your checks

[This article](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) could be a good starting point